# Magento: Product Image upload permission for website specific admin user

Tags: magento-enterprise

We have implemented multi website functionality like

```
1) test1.com 
2) test2.com
3) test3.com
```

We have created admin user based on each website. Here some product is shared with multiple website.

Example: **Product 1** is shared with 3 websites. We want the feature to display image differently based on each website.

Super admin can able to upload and save image store specific.

The problem here is website specific admin users ex:**test3.com** admin user couldn't able to upload/save image for **Product 1** because that product is shared in multiple website.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559763/magento-product-image-upload-permission-for-website-specific-admin-user